# How to solve $\mathrm{d}^n y/\mathrm{d}x^n = (\mathrm{d}y/\mathrm{d}x)^n$ or $(\mathrm{e}^D) y = \mathrm{e}^{(Dy)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, lie-algebras

Is there a general analytical solution for 
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}^ny}{\mathrm{d}x^n} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}\right)^n,\qquad n>2? $$

or equivalently $(\mathrm{e}^D) y = \mathrm{e}^{(Dy)}$ where $\mathrm{D} = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dx}}$ and $\mathrm{e}^D$ is the exponentiatin operator.

For $n=2$, the solution is  $y(x) = c_2 - \log(c_1 + x)$.

Comment: I have edited your question to use MathJax.  Can you please verify that it still says what you want it to say?  Also, can you please provide some context?  What tools do you have at your disposal to solve this differential equation?  How did you get the solution in the case that $n=2$?  What have you attempted to do to solve the more general equation?

Comment: Notice that the derivative of the solution verifies $d^{n-1}z/dx^{n-1}=z^n$, which is autonomous.

Comment: Generally you are really dealing with $y^{(n-1)}=y^n$, up to a constant of integration (which is just an additive constant). Already for $n=3$ you have elliptic functions; for $n>3$ WA does not find any expression.

Comment: I've rolled back to a previous edit to avoid the use of display-style math commands in the title, as per [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/468350) on Meta.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I started the edit when it was the original version, but once I sent it, I noticed someone else edited it. For future reference, is there a way to cancel an edit after submitting?

Comment: @KirkFox Once you submit an edit, there is nothing else that you can do.  However, I don't see any edits made by you in the history of the question, so my guess is that you *suggested* an edit, which would then have been overridden by one of the higher rep users who made edits.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes, that is what I meant to say.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yes this is what I wanted to ask. This came up in a discussion and I wanted to find a general solution. I used z=dy/dx  to solve n=2 which becomes easy to integrate afterwards.